# Python requests returns 200 instead of 301

Tags: python, python-requests

url = "https://www.avito.ma/fr/2_mars/sacs_et_accessoires/Ch%C3%A2les_en_Vrai_Soie_Chanel_avec_boite_38445885.htm"

```
try   
    r = requests.get(url,headers={'User-Agent': ua.random},timeout=timeout) # execute a timed website request
    if r.status_code > 299: # check for bad status
        r.raise_for_status() # if confirmed raise bad status
    else:
        print(r.status_code, url) # otherwise print status code and url
except Exception as e:
     print('\nThe following exception: {0}, \nhas been found found on the following post: "{1}".\n'.format(e,url))
```

**Expected status** = 301 Moved Permanently

You can visit the page or check http://www.redirect-checker.org/index.php with the url for a correct terminal print.

**Returned status** = 200 OK

The page has been moved and it should return the above `301 Moved Permanently`, however it returns a 200. I read the requests doc and checked all the parameters (allow_redirects=False etc.) but I don't think it is a mistake of configuration.

I am puzzled at why requests wouldn't see the redirects.

Any ideas?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: After you've made the request - what do `r.url` and `r.history` show you?

Comment: r.url == `200 https://www.avito.ma/fr/2_mars/sacs_et_accessoires/Ch%C3%A2les_en_Vrai_Soie_Chanel_avec_boite_38445885.htm`, r.history `The following exception: 503 Server Error: Service Unavailable: Back-end server is at capacity for url: https://www.avito.ma/fr/2_mars/sacs_et_accessoires/Ch%C3%A2les_en_Vrai_Soie_Chanel_avec_boite_38445885.htm, 
has been found found on the following post: "https://www.avito.ma/fr/2_mars/sacs_et_accessoires/Ch%C3%A2les_en_Vrai_Soie_Chanel_avec_boite_38445885.htm".

--Return--`.

Comment: Could it be an issue with the server configuration?

Comment: I redid the r.history in `ipdb` and I've pasted the result above.

Comment: Printing `r.history` from the code itself returns: `[<Response [301]>, <Response [301]>]` which should be indeed the right status code. But still I cannot understand how the `history` and the  `status_code` differ ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Python Requests module has the allow_redirect parameter in True by default. I've tested it with False and it gives the 301 code that you're looking for.

[image]

Note after reading your comment above: r.history saves each response_code before the one that you're right now which is saved in r.status_code (only if you leave the parameter in True).

Comment: As indicated in the question I had tried the `allow_redirects=False` hower when you add the parameter, requests appears not to return a `status_code` which breaks the logic of the code unfortunately.

Comment: @Densetsu_No In fact it does return one. As you can see in this [link](https://imgur.com/a/vaNwdkK), I've been able to retrieve the `status code` even after adding the parameter.

Comment: I just tried it in the terminal with the exact same parameters that I have in the code and indeed it returns a `status_code` let me try to understand why it doesn't work when I launch the sample via terminal.

Comment: @Densetsu_No I've tried to add the parameters you have: 1- headers with an User-Agent and 2- the timeout, and it also work. Maybe a misstypo?

Comment: It appears to be a problem with `raise_for_status` [link](https://imgur.com/TUxQ39W).

Comment: @Densetsu_No It is not a problem. `Raise_for_status` only raises an exception if a request is unsuccessfull, a redirect is something expected to happen normally. That's why raise_for_status does nothing. If you want to know if a redirect has been done, you should go for:
`if r.response_code in [300,302]:` Obviously with the parameter in False. If it is in true you should go for: `if r.history:`

Comment: Yes it is absolutely right, stupidly enough I though anything over 299 would raise an error. I resolved the code like this:

`if r.status_code > 299: # check for bad status`
            `print('\n',r.status_code, r.reason, url,'\n') # if confirmed print bad status`

Comment: @Densetsu_No seems good! Keep it going then! Do not forget to close this topic when solved.